# Grails use inherited property within named query

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, named-query

I want to use an inherited property within a named query of a derived instance, in order that I can provide a custom sort of the results.  I am getting an error.

```
package com.example

class Ticket {
    // User is defined elsewhere
    static belongsTo = [user : User]
    String idNumber
}

class SeasonTicket extends Ticket {

    // some custom properties go here

    static namedQueries = {
        locateOrderedSeasonTicketsByUser { user ->
            // all derived instances are in the same table, hence return only the correct derived instances
            eq("class", "com.example.SeasonTicket")

            // return a match on user
            user {
                idEq(user.id)
            }

            // implement custom order
            order "customProperty"
        }
    } << Ticket.namedQueries
}
```

The final line allows any inherited named queries defined in the base class to be used.

I get the following error when running an integration test that calls:

```
SeasonTicket.locateOrderedSeasonTicketsByUser(someUserInstance)
```

> No signature of method: com.example.User.call() is applicable for
>   argument types:
>   (com.example.SeasonTicket$__clinit__closure2_closure3_closure4)
>   values:
>   [com.example.SeasonTicket$__clinit__closure2_closure3_closure4@31ee7d7a]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), last(), save(), any(), getAll(),
>   wait(long)

The integration test was my first attempt at a simple test :

```
void "SeasonTicket.locateOrderedSeasonTicketsByUser finds an object"() {
    given:
    def seasonTicket = new SeasonTicket()
    def user = new User()       
    user.addToSeasonTickets(seasonTicket)
    user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    expect: "we can find one season ticket"
    SeasonTicket.locateOrderedSeasonTicketsByUser(user).list().size() == 1
}
```

It looks as though the user field within the base class is not being recognised.  What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Try rename your query parameter ... It looks like a conflict between `user` parameter of your query and the `user` property of the `Ticket` class.

Comment: Spot on, thanks - I'd thought the user within the query would be treated a bit like as if it were a member variable (i.e. with an implicit 'this') and therefore there would be no conflict with the local parameter passed to the query.  Please would you mind adding as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a naming conflict between your local parameter `user` and your class property 'user'.

This part of your criteria

```
user {
    idEq(user.id)
}
```

will try to call a method on your local parameter `user` which dosn't exist, instead of buidling your query using the `user` property of `Ticket`.

Rename the parameter of your namedQuery `locateOrderedSeasonTicketsByUser`.